# pgfplotstable: Eliminating the First Column

Tags: pgfplotstable

Nothing is shown in the first column of the sample data, yet a zero shows up in the table. How do I remove the zero (0) in column 0?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[paperwidth=50cm,paperheight=5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\noindent\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=&, row sep=\\,
    every head row/.style={%
         before row={\toprule%
         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{P.R.}
         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Boat}
         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Inspecting}
         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{No. Boats}
         &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Ardvaarks}\\
         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Date \& Link}
         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Yard}
         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Agency}
         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Looked}
         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Non-Critical}
         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Critical}\\\midrule},
        },
  every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
  string type,
   ]
    {
    %sample data
      & a1 & 26 & a94.6513 & 0.9995 & T145.6622 & 0.9999  \\
      & b2 & 25 & 84.5684  & 0.8296 & 131.5305  & VV0.8881\\
    }

\end{document}
```

Comment: You may combine `output empty row` and `header=false`. The zero you saw is in fact the name of the first column.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[paperwidth=50cm,paperheight=5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\noindent\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=&, row sep=\\,
    every head row/.style={%
         before row={\toprule%
         {P.R.}
         & {Boat}
         &{Inspecting}
         &{No. Boats}
         &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Ardvaarks}\\
         {Date \& Link}
         &{Yard}
         &{Agency}
         &{Looked}
         &{Non-Critical}
         &{Critical}\\\midrule},
        },
  every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
  string type,
   ]
    {
    %sample data
       a1 & 26 & a94.6513 & 0.9995 & T145.6622 & 0.9999  \\
       b2 & 25 & 84.5684  & 0.8296 & 131.5305  & VV0.8881\\
    }
\end{document}
```